# how to create a mac executable for my electronJs application that supports php with the ELECTRON-4-PHP-master project taken from github

Tags: javascript, laravel-10

when I run my application with the command "npm start" my application works fine but when I create the executable with the command "electron-packager. --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --no-asar --icon=icons/logo.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds" the application that I created only works if my application executed with the command "npm start" remains running so the server of the application that I created does not start by itself

please help me

I tried to use the start() function of the PHPServer class so that the server runs directly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.